# IPython Notebook - pandas.DataFrame (sorts automatically a column when not desired)

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I'm having some issues when I try to add a column into a pandas.DataFrame.

I'm trying to add a column with some "traslation" from an index into its name (that traslation has been imported from a csv). But when I try to add it, the column shows the data in the same order as in the csv and not with the index in giving to it.

What's weird is that if I print the data I'm trying to put in the column by itself, the data shows properly.

```
count = pd.value_counts(y_train, sort=True, ascending=True)
table_index = np.arange(n_classes)

result = pd.DataFrame()
result['SignIndex'] = count.index
result['Counts'] = count.values
column = list_signals['SignName'][count.index]
result['Signal'] = column

result.head()
```

This is what it prints:

```
    SignIndex   Counts  Signal
0   0           180     Speed limit (20km/h)
1   19          180     Speed limit (30km/h)
2   37          180     Speed limit (50km/h)
3   27          210     Speed limit (60km/h)
4   41          210     Speed limit (70km/h)
```

But if you print the variable column by itself, this is what it prints:

```
column


SignIndex
0                                  Speed limit (20km/h)
19                          Dangerous curve to the left
37                                  Go straight or left
27                                          Pedestrians
41                                    End of no passing
42    End of no passing by vehicles over 3.5 metric ...
```

Does someone knows why is this happening?

Thanks is advance!

Comment: How did you "print the variable column by itself"?  What is `list_signals`?  Your code is a bit strange because you seem to use `result` before it's defined.  Can you provide a self-contained example demonstrating the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I dind't mention that I'm using and IPython Notebook, and I forgot to change what you point after a few tries, let me edit the code again

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve. Do you want to just print out `result['Signal']`? Otherwise, could you please include in your question the expected behavior?

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is add `result['Signal']` ordered in the same way as presented when printing the `column` variable below.

Comment: `list_signals` is a variable that I imported from a csv file that has the translation from each `SignIndex` to each `string`. The correct "translation" is the one that is done when printed `column`, not `result['Signal']`

Comment: If you assign a Series as a column in a DataFrame, the index of your Series is matched with the index of the DataFrame.  I suspect that is what is going on here.  Try adding `result.set_index("SignIndex", inplace=True)` after your line `result['SignIndex'] = count.index`.  Or, try doing `result['Signal'] = column.values` (using `values` as you did for `count`).  Or, try providing a self-contained, runnable example.

Comment: Yes, you're right @BrenBarn. I removed `column` and what sorted the indexes of `count` using `.sort_index()` as I also have to plot a bar chart. Then set `result['Signal']` to `list_signals['SignName'][count.index]` and everything looks fine now! :)

Comment: @CristianAlonsoVallejo If you found the solution to your problem, you may post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise, it you feel this is unlikely to be helpful to others, you may close your own question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that @iled, I hope it can help someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BrenBarn said, if you assign a Series as a column in a DataFrame, the index of your Series is matched with the index of the DataFrame.

So to solve my problem, this is what I finally did:

```
count = pd.value_counts(y_train).sort_index()

result = pd.DataFrame()
result['SignIndex'] = count.index
result['Counts'] = count.values
result['Signal'] = list_signals['SignName'][count.index]

result = result.sort_values(by=['Counts'], ascending=True)
result = result.reset_index(drop=True)

result.head()
```

And this is the result of printing it:

```
    SignIndex   Counts  Signal
0   0           180     Speed limit (20km/h)
1   37          180     Go straight or left
2   19          180     Dangerous curve to the left
3   32          210     End of all speed and passing limits
4   27          210     Pedestrians
5   41          210     End of no passing
```

Thanks all for your help!

Comment: Thanks for putting it all up as a nice answer :) You may as well accept your own answer (click the green thick on the left of the answer).

Comment: Thank you @iled for helping me :)